# How to assign a string value in Objective C using ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Using ARC, is it now OK to assign a string value like this:

```
 self.userName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:self.currentParsedCharacterData];
```

Or does that still cause a memory leak, thus requiring me to assign it like this:

```
NSString *tmpString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:self.currentParsedCharacterData];
self.userName = tmpString;
```

Comment: Go watch WWDC 2011 session 323. It will explain ARC much more fully than anyone will be able to with an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet is just fine under ARC, and is the better of the two ways. Apple has an example like this in the [Transitioning to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226) guide:

```
- (void)contrived {
    Person *aPerson = [[Person alloc] init];
    [aPerson setFirstName:@"William"];
    [aPerson setLastName:@"Dudney"];
    [aPerson setYearOfBirth:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:2011]];
    NSLog(@"aPerson: %@", aPerson);
}
```

and says:

> ARC takes care of memory management so that neither the `Person` nor the `NSNumber` objects are leaked.

The `setYearOfBirth:` message with an `alloc`ed `NSNumber` corresponds to your snippet.

The compiler understands that, in the first case, `aPerson` is going out of scope and needs to be released before that happens, and, in the second case, that there is no explicit reference to the `NSNumber` object and that it must be either released or put into the autorelease pool. It takes care of both these requirements on your behalf.

Comment: There's a typo in that guide (line 4 of the function, `aPerson:` should be `aPerson`). Should file a bug I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with ARC it is ok. In fact, I would recommend the first way you have it implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Either of your examples is fine. There is no difference between the two as far as memory management/ARC goes.